# Google Datastore merge creates a new unwanted property

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, google-cloud-datastore

I am currently trying to write an API in Typescript to store and retrieve entities from a Google Cloud Datastore instance.

I have managed to get `GET`, `POST`, and `DELETE` working, however my `PUT` API call works but creates an unwanted property after testing the API call using Postman.

Here is the code for the `PUT` API call which is routed to `/api/offer/:id`

```js
export async function updateOffer(req: any, res: any) {
    try {
        const offerKey = datastore.key(["offer", datastore.int(req.params.id)]);
       
        var offer = await datastore.get(offerKey);
        
        if (req.body.status == null || req.body.status == undefined) {
            res.status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST).send({
                message: "Offer could not be updated as `status` property was left empty",
                IsSuccess: false,
            });

            logger.error("Offer could not be updated as `status` property was left empty");   
        } else {
            offer.status = req.body.status;

            await datastore.merge({
                key: offerKey,
                data: offer
            });
    
            res.status(StatusCodes.OK).send({
                message: "Offer has been updated",
                IsSuccess: true,
                data: offer
            });
    
            logger.info("Offer has been updated");
        }

    } catch (e) {
        res.status(StatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST).send({
            message: "Unable to update offer",
            IsSuccess: false,
            error: JSON.stringify(e)
        });

        logger.error("Unable to update offer: " + e);
    }
}
```

What the code does, is that it only allows for updating of one property of the offer entity, called `status`. Therefore the method I am using in this API call, is to:

1. Get the entity first by the param `:id`
2. Set the status as the new status specified in `req.body.status`
3. Merge the original entity with the new created entity

However this creates an unwanted property as seen in this screenshot

[image: An extra property called 0 gets created upon the merge]

As seen in the image, an extra property called `0` gets added to the entity which consists of the JSON representation of the entity. I am not sure why this is happening and if this is even the right way to go about doing this.

Comment: The reason I am using the `datastore.merge` function is because it is used in one of the examples in the Google Datastore Node Client API here https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/blob/master/samples/tasks.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datastore.get() returns an array, so when you pass offer as the data parameter of merge, it is an array and not an entity.  The entity data you are looking for is thus in position 0 of the array, and that's why you get a property named '0'.

You can fix this by changing your get call to `const [offer] = datastore.get(...)` as suggested in https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#retrieving_an_entity .